# How to populate rows of jQuery datatable with JSON object sent back from Spring MVC?

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring-mvc, datatables

I have a *Java* (Spring MVC) backend that returns *POJOs* as *JSON* objects as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getWidgetsByType", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<WidgetVO> getWidgetsByType(@RequestParam("type") String type)
{
    return widgetDAO.getWidgetsByType(token);
}   

public class WidgetVO {
    private String type;
    private String name;
    private boolean isAwesome;

    // Getters and setters, etc.
}
```

In the frontend I'm trying to call `/getWidgetsByType` from inside a *jQuery* `$.getJSON` call, and then use the *JSON* results coming back from that to populate a [datatable](http://datatables.net/).  Specifically, I want the datatable to appear inside a `<div>` tag that is currently empty at page load as follows:

```
<div id="#table-to-display"></div>

var t = getTypeFromDOM();

$.getJSON(
    url: "/getWidgetsByType",
    data: {
        type: t
    },
    success: function() {
        // How do I extract the JSON version of the List<WidgetVO>'s coming
        // back from the server and use them to populate the table?
        $("#table-to-display").datatable();
    }
);
```

I would like the `datatable` to contain the same *columns* as the *fields* of the `WidgetVO` (type, name, isAwesome), all as `String` values (no renderers, etc.).

Thanks in advance for any help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html) from the datatable site gives you all the details required.

Example JS code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "scripts/server_processing.php" // for you it will be - /getWidgetsByType
  } );
} );
```

Your json should be something like this

```
{
  "sEcho": 1,
  "iTotalRecords": "57",
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": "57",
  "aaData": [
    [],[],[],...
  ]
}
```

[Here's](http://live.datatables.net/#javascript,html,live) example showing to set the column names on the fly.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks @bhb (+1) - but are `bProcessing` and `bServerSide` datatable params or app-specific query string params? What if my server-side is not a PHP file but a Spring MVC handler that gets mapped from the URL `/getWidgetsByType`? Thanks again!

Comment: It should not matter as long as your server side code pushes json format shown above. If that is difficult for some reason, you can also read from other sources. Check [this](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html). If your json is an array of objects(instead of array of array as shown above) try something like [this](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/object_data.html)

Comment: So do I even need to call `$.getJSON`, or does the `$("#table-to-display").datatable() { ... };` call do it for me?

Comment: No probs :). So if the json is an array of array like `{demo:[[],[]...]}`, then the order of the array elements specifies the column order.

Comment: datatable does it for you... no need to call `$.getJSON`.

Comment: That's so cool. Thanks again - all the lightbulbs (well, most of them) just went on. thanks for helping me connect the dots

Comment: Hi Everyone, Can anyone please validate my json string: {
  "iTotalRecords": 20,
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": 5,
  "aaData": [
    {
      "name": "Sandeep1",
      "mark": "201"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sandeep2",
      "mark": "202"
    },
    
  ]
}

Answer (score 2):

1.Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
@ResponseBody
String listUsersJson(ModelMap model) throws JSONException {
    int no=1;
    JSONArray userArray = new JSONArray();
    for (TileType tT: tD.getAll()){   
        String n=Integer.toString(no);
        String id=Integer.toString(tT.getTileTypeId());          
        String[] value =
        {n,
         tT.getTileTypeName(),
         tT.getTileTypeDensity()         
        };   
        userArray.put(value);
        no++;
    }
    String x=userArray.toString();
    String replace1=x.replace("{", "[");
    String replace2=replace1.replace("}","]");
    String replace3=replace2.replace(":",",");
   return ("{\"aaData\":"+replace3+"}");        
}
```

2.Dao

```
 @Override
public List<TileType> getAll() {
    Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<TileType>list=new ArrayList<TileType>();
    try{
    Query query=session.createQuery("from TileType T order by T.tileTypeId DESC");
    list=query.list();
    }
    catch(HibernateException he){}
return list;
   }
```

3.Javascript

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
     "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sAjaxSource": "/data/tipeTile/json",
    "sDom": "<'row'<'col-xs-6'l><'col-xs-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-xs-6'i><'col-xs-6'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
        "sSearch": ""
    }
         });
```

4.Html

```
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width: 50px">No</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Density</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Hope this Help

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get the appropriate JSON data from Spring to DataTable is that instead of returning a list of your entity, return a map like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getWidgetsByType", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, WidgetVO> getWidgetsByType(@RequestParam("type") String type) {
    Map<String, WidgetVO> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("WidgetVO", widgetDAO.getWidgetsByType(token));
    return result;
}
```

That's it and now you can have access to your objects:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "ajax": "data/objects.txt",
    "dataSrc": "WidgetVO",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "type" },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "isAwesome" }

    ]
});
```

});