# How to populate dynamic table with JSON object sent back from Spring MVC?

Tags: jquery, json, html, spring, hibernate

I have to populate dynamic table with JSON data, which is given by service URL, I am using Spring+Hibernate, form that I am giving service Service URL, Please check my getData.html file, please check it, It is not working properly. 
I have taken this example form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841510/how-to-populate-rows-of-jquery-datatable-with-json-object-sent-back-from-spring)

**getData.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <!-- <script>
            var t=getTypeFromDOm();
            $.getJSON(
                url:"localhost:8080/HomeServiceProvider/booking/getAllBookingDetails"
                data:{
                    type:t
                },
                success: operate(){
                    $("#table_to_display").datatable();
                }
            )
        </script> -->

        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#table_to_display').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "http://www.service4homes.com:8080/HomeServiceProvider/booking/getAllBookingDetails" // for you it will be - /getWidgetsByType
          } );
        } );
        </script>       
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="table_to_display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My JSON Data**

```
{   
  custName: "Navin"
  custMobile: "8123456789"
  custEmail: "abc@gmail.com"
  custAddress: "BAngalore"
}
```

Comment: Isn't working, as in it sits at home all day watcing daytime TV? How isn't it working, do you see a table at all ?

Comment: Should be noted that your `onload` thingy has a strange character in it ?